# Get the highest days after due date in single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord

In Rails 6 application I have an Invoice table. Customer has many invoices and Invoice belongs to customer, In the invoice table, I have the field due_date.

I need to get the highest days past the due_date for the invoice.

To get the invoices details from a customer I use the following scope

```
scope :days_past_due_date, -> { where('invoice_status NOT IN (?) and due_amount > ? and due_date < ?',
[Invoice.invoice_statuses['voided'], Invoice.invoice_statuses['deleted'], Invoice.invoice_statuses["paid"]],
0.0, Date.today)}
```

So my code is `customer.invoices.days_past_due_date` this will get the invoices of a customer in array filtering the due_date and invoice_status filter.

There are multiple invoices I need to find the days for the invoice having the highest days over the due_date with the days pass calculation.

so if due_date is 28 October and today it's 31 October so 3 days pass over due_date.

I need to get the highest number of days that pass the due_date of the invoices.

Comment: you can specify the database for better resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sql `GROUP BY`, rails `.group()`.

```rb
Invoice.group(:customer_id).pluck(:customer_id, Invoice.arel_table[:due_date].minimum)
```

This will get you the earliest due date for every customer_id. Should be enough to do the rest with ruby, or you can do it in the database with a slightly more complex query.

```rb
Invoice.group(:customer_id).pluck(:customer_id, (Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(Date.today) - Invoice.arel_table[:due_date]).maximum)
```

This will get the maximum days past due for every customer_id. If you only want to consider invoices that match your scope, just add that scope there.

```rb
Invoice.days_past_due_date.group(:customer_id).pluck(:customer_id, (Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(Date.today) - Invoice.arel_table[:due_date]).maximum)
```

Comment: I got NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Class:0x0000556a367a4f90>      
I used it in customer.rb customer model by
self.invoices.days_past_due_date.group(:customer_id).pluck(:customer_id, (Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(Date.today) - Invoice[:due_date]).maximum)

I think issue with (Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(Date.today) - Invoice[:due_date]).maximum

Comment: I have a local override so I don't have to write `arel_table`. Edited the answer to not depend on it. Sorry.

Comment: I got it now thanks but it shows the 1 day less is it consider the end day(today)?

Comment: Right now it gives the difference between today and the date in the database. If the date is the same, the difference is 0. Add 1 as need be if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **(Postgres)**

This will add an `overdue_by` `Integer` column to the results (days)

which you can access like `User.first.invoices.days_past_due_date.first.overdue_by`

```
scope :days_past_due_date, -> { 
  select(Arel.sql %(invoices.*, CURRENT_DATE - due_date::DATE overdue_by))
  .where('invoice_status NOT IN (?) and due_amount > ? and due_date < ?',
    [Invoice.invoice_statuses['voided'], Invoice.invoice_statuses['deleted'], Invoice.invoice_statuses["paid"]], 0.0, Date.today
  )
}
```